# PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException Module 'newrelic' already loaded craft 3

Tags: craft3, admin, modules, upgrades, newrelic

I upgraded Craft 2 to Craft 3.3. Sometimes I am getting an error in admin like below when saving entries or taking some URL.

> PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException Module 'newrelic' already loaded craft 3

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Not really related to Craft or the update from Craft 2 to 3.  You'll probably want to contact your hosting provider.  It sounds like there are multiple attempts at loading the newrelic module in your php.ini file.